# Boxplot/dotplot in order to visualize differences

Tags: r

I have a data like below:

```
structure(c(170007558.204312, 3151225505.1608, 3228057474.07417, 
            131519574.092116, 2149477968.81888, 1215136556.10718, 160433707.919651, 
            5956246992.50776, 2558167135.01689, 3245672969.97675, 169100005.594611, 
            354825870.40362, 1576805307.20395, 416870647.054276, 3399878725.25131, 
            370231854.581136, 1122345506.21081, 2305206508.74322, 2232159732.1229, 
            47308024.505238, 1241395335.9693, 2436980532.07484, 1128618969.34889, 
            3100422173.38636, 288672329.474137, 2987525983.71596, 3287998115.95645, 
            152127227.856302, 1994141536.64711, 1239229228.43808, 145289220.860244, 
            5376086563.26477, 2288378963.83637, 3084446977.22353, 63805766.33001, 
            336627137.967236, 1459357039.40439, 338887231.409886, 2712985868.45896, 
            351047105.326338, 1097447659.97404, 2042978821.82768, 2197665385.69067, 
            38049639.2725552, 1145898075.14945, 2394369287.02634, 941453724.349293, 
            2879533609.52787), .Dim = c(24L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("Mark", 
                                                                     "Chris", "Tom", "Tim", "Hank", "Taylor", 
                                                                     "Moniqe", "Rasp", "Greg", "Mephist", "Daniel", 
                                                                     "Moussa", "Ivan", "Treate", "Argen", "Tupol", 
                                                                     "Gotrek", "Marcel", "Gotae", "Ernsten", "Alfred", 
                                                                     "Katrin", "Paul", "Marten"), NULL))
```

I would like to perform pairwise comparison between column `1` and `2`. The important thing is that all of those rows create somehow an entity. So in general two groups are compared by members. I just wanted to show that members of these groups are really similar. I thought about simple boxplot/dotplot but how the hell normalize this data to put everything on one graph ? Do you have in mind any other comparison ? How to put numbers from two data sets into one graph ?

EDIT:
Just forget to mention that I would like to avoid calculating the ratio between them and plotting that output.

Comment: If it's only point-to-point, what about [slopegraphs](https://acaird.github.io/computers/r/2013/11/27/slopegraphs-ggplot)?

Comment: As I already have mentioned it sound like a great idea but the graph showed by Jimbou looks a bit messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try

```
library(reshape2)
dl <- melt(d)
plot(dl[,2], dl[,3])
for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
  lines(1:2, c(d[i,]))
}
```

[image]

You can also try a ggplot solution

```
ggplot(dl, aes(x=factor(Var2), y= value, group=Var1, label=Var1)) + geom_line() + 
  geom_text(data = subset(dl, Var2 == "1"), hjust = 1) +
  geom_text(data = subset(dl, Var2 == "2"), hjust = 0) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

In the tidyverse you can write

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
as.data.frame(d) %>%
  add_column(Names=rownames(d)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Names) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value,label=Names)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill="grey") +
  geom_line(aes(group=Names)) + 
  geom_text_repel(size=3, color="red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Another way would be to turn the plot and show the names on the y-axis.

```
ggplot(dl, aes(x= value, y=Var1, col = factor(Var2))) + geom_point()  + theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can also try to median normalize the data to better compare the individuals.

Comment: It looks like the output I could accept but don't you think it is a bit too messy ? If we would be able to put the labels for these dots without messing it completely that would be great.

Comment: you can use `geom_text_repel` in the `ggrepel` package to accomplish this

Comment: @Jimbou, both solution look nice. Especially, I appreciate the second one!

Comment: I have just one question. Is there any way to deal with overlapping dots ? Can you make them visible somehow ? It looks more like missing dot for a second data set. In my original data I have this problem.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver add some alpha using `geom_point(alpha=.5, size=5)`?